# Determine Desktop, mobile and Tablet in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I am having a scenario where my React component renders same UI in Desktop and Tablet but different UI in Mobile.

Below is the way I am using to determine Desktop and Mobile. How can I determine and include Tablet also ?

```
const isMobile = (userAgent = navigator.userAgent) => /Mobi/.test(userAgent);

export const Mobile = ({ children }) => (isMobile() ? children : null);
export const Desktop = ({ children }) => (isMobile() ? null : children);
```

Then in the react component I am using like this, In the below how could i determine Tablet mode. For Desktop or Tablet I need to render a same component.

```xml
<MyCompSection>
    <Desktop> // or Tablet, but how to determine Tablet
        <MyComponent/>
    </Desktop>
    <Mobile>
        <MyComponent/>
    </Mobile>
</MyCompSection>
```

I see that the user agent for Tablet also returns as a Mobile.
What is the best practice in this scenario ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [react-responsive](https://github.com/contra/react-responsive) to render different components based on device width.